# When the input is blank the last chip should be deleted on pressing Backspace

Tags: reactjs, eventhandler

[image: Screen shot for reference]When the Input is blank and user presses delete button the last chip should be deleted. 
You can find the sandbox link below which can provide a clear picture.

https://codesandbox.io/s/thirsty-glade-my5xk

Any help will be appreciated.

I have tried `onKeyUp` function but it isn't the solution I need.

// displaying chips

```
{this.state.emails.map(email => (
  <div key={email}>
    {email}

    <button
      type="button"
      onClick={() =>  this.handleDelete(email)}
    >
      &times;
    </button>
  </div>
))}
```

// Input field

```
<input
  placeholder="Type or paste email addresses and press `Enter`"
  value={this.state.value}
  onChange={this.handleChange}
  onKeyDown={this.handleKeyDown}
/>
```

// Delete event handeler

```
handleDelete = (toBeRemoved) => {
  this.setState({
    emails: this.state.emails.filter(email => email !== toBeRemoved)
  });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (evt.key === "Backspace" && this.state.value === "") {
  evt.preventDefault();
  let emails = this.state.emails
  if (emails.length > 0) {
    emails.pop()
    return this.setState({emails})
  }
}
```

This should check if value is empty and `evt.key` is Backspace then remove last item from the emails array.

Comment: I have put the above condition inside ```handleKeyDown```. I am using mac so I have replaced Backspace with Delete, but it is not working

Comment: I just updated my answer little bit. Reason is I did not tested earlier and I made some error with using `pop()` but this might help.

Comment: Thanks @harsh it solved my query. I need to implement one more thing though

Comment: How about if I want to delete the chip on clicking twice the backspace. Suppose on the first click I want to apply some styles to the last chip and when clicking again it should delete it.

Comment: I would suggest keeping counter on state, so something like,
```
if (evt.key === "Backspace") {
  if (this.state.bsCounter === 1) {
    // all work for removing chip from earlier answer
  }
  this.setState({bsCounter: (this.state.bsCounter+1)%2});
}
```

Comment: I tried something like this ```this.setState({ counter: this.state.counter + 1 });
        if (this.state.counter === 1) {
          if (emails.length > 0) {
            emails.pop();
            return this.setState({ emails });
          }
        }
        if (this.state.counter === 2) {
          return <h1>hey</h1>;
        }```

Comment: That should not work because you are updating your state before using in if statement. Check in my answer above and you can use `else` with the second `if` for your style change. That should be straight forward.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199756/discussion-between-amnah-khatun-and-harsh-modi).

Answer (score 1):

You can remove your `handlekeyUp` and handle the backspace key in your `handleKeyDown` handler like this:

```
handleKeyDown = evt => {

  if (["Enter", ",", "Backspace"].includes(evt.key)) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    if (evt.key === "Backspace") {
      // Remove last email
      this.setState({
        emails: this.state.emails.slice(0, -1);
      })

      return;
    }

    var email = this.state.value.trim();

    if (email) {
      this.setState({
        emails: [...this.state.emails, email],
        value: ""
      });
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: For Mac user do I have to replace ```Backspace``` with ```Delete```

Comment: I think you should be fine with "Backspace"